# Can I know if the task pane is pinned or not in outlook web add in?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I got article saying how to implement a pinnable task pane

[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane)

But can I know on run time if the task pane is pinned or not? Cannot find anything like that is `Office.js`

Answer (score 0):

@Frostless, can you shed more light on the scenario you are working on?
Why does your add-in need to know whether it's pinned or not?

There is currently no API/Event to determine if an add-in is pinned. You will get the itemChanged event if it is pinned, but that will only happen after pinning & item switch.

Suggestions for new features can be made at [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). It would be helpful to know what scenario you are trying to solve with the pinning information.

Comment: I want to a `ifPinned` check when a button is clicked, if pinned go back to the entry view, otherwise close the task pane.

Comment: Would you be able to give us more details on your scenario and clarify what you mean by entry view?